# Why are there two instances of the ViewController and how to fix it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

First I'll give you a short overview.

I'm ...

1. creating a new cocoa project
2. customizing the AppDelegate (see listing 1)
3. adding a "Custom View" to my MainMenu.xib
4. creating a new Cocoa Class (NSViewController + XIB) in the project, calling it MyTableViewController.*
5. adding a "Table View" to the recently added ViewController, like described in [LINK](http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/025-NSTableView.pl)
6. the code of my MyTableViewController can be seen in listing 2

Now to my problem.
The table and it's content is shown.
But if I select an item of the table and press a button (connected to `(IBAction)action:(id)sender`) on this subview, `<NSIndexSet: 0x60000022c100>(no indexes)` is shown in the output (see: `selectedColumnIndexes`).
After experimenting a while, I found out that there are two instances of the MyTableViewController class.

Can someone please explain me why there are two instances and help me to fix this problem.

Thx

listing 1:

```
// FILE: AppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class MyTableViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSViewController *        currentViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyTableViewController *     myTableViewController;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *myview;
@end

// FILE: AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
[self changeViewController];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
// Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication {
return YES;
}

- (void)changeViewController
{
if ([self.currentViewController view] != nil) {
    [[self.currentViewController view] removeFromSuperview];
}
switch (0) {
    case 0:
    default:
        if (self.myTableViewController == nil) {
            _myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        self.currentViewController = self.myTableViewController;
        NSLog(@"EndView");
        break;
}

[self.myview addSubview:[self.currentViewController view]];
[[self.currentViewController view] setFrame:[self.myview bounds]];
[self.currentViewController setRepresentedObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[[[self.currentViewController view] subviews] count]]];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"viewController"];
NSLog(@"ViewController changed");
}

@end
```

listing 2:

```
// FILE: MyTableViewController.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface MyTableViewController : NSViewController
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tview;
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender;
@end

// FILE: MyTableViewController.m
#import "MyTableViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MyTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

- (NSUInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableViewObj {
return 2;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
if ([tableView tableColumns][0] == tableColumn) {
    return @"bla";
} else if ([tableView tableColumns][1] == tableColumn) {
    return @"blub";
}
NSLog(@"dropped through tableColumn identifiers");
return NULL;
}

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {
//    selectedColumnIndexes
NSLog(@"%@", [self.tview selectedColumnIndexes]);
}
@end
```

[image: FilesOwner-Connections]
[image: TableView-Connections]
[image: TableView.app]

Comment: Why are you using the `@property` `assign` attribute?

Comment: See method `changeViewController`. There are different ViewControllers in the real project (I'm switching between them). `currentViewController` is a pointer to the current used ViewController. This code is just the essential part of the problem.

Comment: But why `assign` instead of `weak`?

Comment: I tried `weak`, but problem stays the same.

Comment: Is your data-source method ``-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row`` ever called? Also, you should be returning ``nil``, not ``NULL`` for this method.

Comment: As you can see (see new pic), my table is visible and content is shown.

Comment: In the action method triggered by your button push do some logging. Check the basics: What's your table's identifier? Does your table report having two columns? Iterate over these columns and log their ``identifiers``, are they what you entered in Interface Builder? Does your table permit columns to be selected? Extensive logging (also known as 'caveman debugging') is handy in situations like this. Of course, you should do all this *after having selected a column*.

Comment: By the way, when you say *'... if I select an item of the table...'* by *item* do you mean a row or a column? As it stands your checking to see which columns (vertical) have been selected, not which rows (horizontal) is that what you mean to do? In your screenshot you've selected ROWS not COLUMNS. To see which rows are selected you need ``[-NSTableView selectedRowIndexes]``.

Comment: OMG ... m( ... autocomplete error. Your right. `selectedRowIndexes` makes all fine. This and the info with the "blue object cubes" solved my problem. Thx thx thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two instances of a class, when you only expect/want one, can be caused by failing to appreciate that objects in your xib files are themselves actual automatically-generated instances of that class.

Have you dragged a blue cube into either of your xib files and set it's class to your view controller subclass? If you have, then this will account for one of the objects that you're seeing - Apple's machinery creates it on your behalf. The second object is the one created by you, in code, in your `changeViewController` method.

I get the impression that you're simply trying to create a window, which contains an `NSTableView`, which in turn gets its data from your own `NSViewController` subclass. Is this correct? If it is then you should do away with the second xib file, and instead just use the xib created for you when you created the project.

### In Brief

1. Drag a blue object cube into the Interface Builder dock and set it's subclass to `MyTableViewController` using the *Identity Inspector*.
2. With your view controller blue-cube selected go to the *Connections Inspector* and drag from the `view` option to your table view - you must make sure you're dragging to the table view, not the scroll view or clip view that encloses it.
3. Select the table view (again, make sure it really is the table view you've selected), and go to it's Connections Inspector. Drag from the `data source` and `delegate` options to your blue view-controller cube.
4. Implement the relevant data-soruce methods

*Hint*: If you aren't sure which inspector is which, open the right sidebar in Xcode and select a xib file from the left file-viewer sidebar. Sit the cursor over each of the icons at the top of the right sidebar and the tool tip will tell you which is which.

### Update

A good way of identifying specific objects, and something that can assist with debugging, is to set their `identifier`. In the attributes inspector, this is the restoration ID. Do this for your `NSTableView` instance, and for your `NSTableColumn` instances. Then, in your data-source methods do some logging with them - for instance does the table view passed as the first argument for this methods have the expected `identifier`, what about the table columns?

Comment: 2nd paragraph sounds interessting! 3rd paragraph will be fine for a simple window, but not for my case. Your brief instructions sounds correct. It's the same I've done to `MyTableViewController.*` (see my Link above).

Comment: If you're creating a single table-view instance, and you want to keep your second, code-loaded, xib, you shouldn't have any blue object cubes that reference your view controller *anywhere* in your project. The only cube that should reference your view controller as its class is the *File's Owner* cube in your second xib file.

Comment: Ok, I had an object cube inside of my MyTableViewController.xib. I removed it and connected the File's Owner instead. But as you can see in the (new) pics, it didn't work for `selectedColumnIndexes`.